# HTML "Table" with scrolling middle cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I've gone through dozens of examples in Stack Overflow but I just can't quite seem to get this right and it's starting to make me wish I'd chosen a different career!

I need a fixed height and fixed width table with three rows.

Row 1 will be variable height and should grow and shrink according to the content, with no vertical scroll bar.

Row 3 should be fixed height at the bottom of the table.

Row 2 should take up all the remaining space but should contain a vertical scroll bar if the content is too big.

Basically, this is to display an email message to the user. Row 1 will contain all the headers and any optional headers, attachments, etc. (which is why it needs to be variable height).

Row 2 is the body of the message, with a scroll bar.

Row 3 is for action buttons, Delete, Forward, etc.

The whole thing needs to be fixed height and width because I need to embed it in to a JQuery dialog DIV.

In my question title I've put table in quotes because I'm happy to have a CSS-only solution, provided it works as described. The key goal for me is that we achieve the functionality above in a cross-browser approach.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Could you please put into http://jsfiddle.net what you allready setup/tried?

Comment: In order for Row 2 to have a scrollbar it will have to have a fixed height. This may be a percentage height (which would grow based on screen resolution), but it still needs to be limited.

Comment: @DamienOvereem I've never used jsfiddle.net before personally. Will certainly do that next time. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @JoelEtherton thanks for the advice. The solution from Abody97 is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, here's a demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/9vwYn/).

What I did was to not include the text directly in the middle cell, but give it `position: relative;`, then create a `div` inside it with the following:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
overflow: auto;
```

Which, as you can see in the demo above, does the job.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. Whilst I can't agree about the Glee thing, the solution is Exactly what I need. Big +1.

Comment: @Chris, I just used your tid-bit of code.  You rock!  (Mine was similar.  Table.  Three Rows.  Fixed height top.  Fixed height bottom.  Middle portion to fill the rest - but mine with no overflow).

Comment: Bummer, just discovered this fails in IE 11. :(