# IE11 absolute position within a table

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, html5-canvas, css-position

I have found threads similar (here), but can not work-out a solution.

In every browser I've tested (Opera, Chrome, Edge, Firefox) what I am doing works. In IE11: Not at all.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UBq5Nb082x0/Tw7KfsY6EWI/AAAAAAAABwE/Joe2aqsoI0k/s1600/maltese_puppy.jpg";

    function start() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
      if (canvas == null) {
        return;
      }
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="start();" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; height: 1px;">
        Hi, I'm cute!
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;">
          <canvas id="imageCanvas" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="border: solid 5px red; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    Your browser does not support the <code>canvas</code> element.
    </canvas>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/krsevs46/

All I'm asking to do is keep the picture completely "dock filled" (can't find another expression other than something I've used from WinForms programming).

This means that as you size the browser, none of the picture will get cropped.  You should always see the whole picture, from the paws to the top of the head.

I have read that all I have to do is swap the `position: relative;` on the `td` tag, and replace it with a `div` tag with `position: relative`, but surrounding my other `div` tag.  That fails miserably. I'm at my wits end (and my follow up question in another thread is why the canvas draws this picture so terribly compared to the original!, but I digress).

EDIT: To further elaborate what I mean by dock-filling the image:

Here is Chrome, working (the first row takes just enough space to fit the text, then the second row of the table fills all remaining space with an image): [image]

And when I size the window it is in, the image remains "filled": [image]

Now, with IE, that same code, I see no image whatsoever.  But if I use static positioning (remove position relative and position absolute), IE doesn't dock fill the image: [image]

And when you shrink the window, you no longer see part of the image (the paws and lower half), I want it squeezed in there: [image]

EDIT2:

Vadim's answer is close, but when the window gets to about 100 pixels, it starts chopping instead of filling.  This is the "last mile", that is taking me so long!  As I will be displaying an image that will be shrunk to 50-100 pixels.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify why do you need absolute positioning here? Static positioning works well here even in IE.

Comment: I would gladly take any solution!  Do you have a quick example? Or could you clarify a bit more?

Comment: Just removing `position: relative;` from `td` and `position: absolute` from `div` makes it working OK. And it's unclear why do you need absolute positioning here.

Comment: Im not sure what iteration of trying to get this to work, led me to absolute positioning (as I did find that bit of code on stackoverflow) ... but now Im down this rabbit hole!  Im typing on a phone, let me go run to a pc and try your suggestion.  Thanks much for reaching out, I appreciate it.  Be right back!

Comment: OK, I tried that.  It didn't achieve what I'm looking for.  I did elaborate a bit more - to describe what I mean by "dock - fill".  I hope you don't mind.  And again, thanks for helping out!  (And this explains how I started using absolute positioning - I was looking for that dock fill look, and some stackoverflow answer led me to that absolute position bit of code, that works terrific in every browser except IE11. Yuck)

Comment: I've been programming for Windows Forms for 3 years and I know what `Dock: Fill` means. You can safely remove wrapping `div` and place `canvas` directly in `td`. `canvas` with `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` will do it's job (occupy all table cell).

Comment: Oh, my bad.  No slight against you.  Trust me.  Just wanted to make sure you were on the same page as me.  I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: I saw your edits right now. Maybe your `td` has some `padding`. Remove them using `padding: 0`

Comment: OK, now I remember what went wrong with that solution.  Here's a jsfiddle with your suggestions: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld124gtp/ ... It looks great at first glance, but once you start to size the window (shrink it), once the 2nd row is about 100pixels in height (and of course lower), it starts cropping (where you no longer see the paws and lower half).  My real code won't use an image of a dog, but a wavelength image (of some wav audio).  And I expect that image to squeeze into about a 50-100 pixel height.  And I noticed it kept getting chopped at that height.  So close!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it.  I kind of hinted at this in my original post, about another div tag.  Which is one of a few minor things I did, but it was my placement of this tag that was wrong.

Anyhow, I have a new jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/d9ywch31/

Here's my code from my original post, but with the slight modifications I made to get this to work in IE (and still work in Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Edge).  I added comments to detail the changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UBq5Nb082x0/Tw7KfsY6EWI/AAAAAAAABwE/Joe2aqsoI0k/s1600/maltese_puppy.jpg";
    img.onload = start; ///// change #1 - for IE had to call start from here, instead of body tag onload

    function start() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
      if (canvas == null) {
        return;
      }
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;"> <!-- change #2 - now start is called in javascript -->
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
      <tr>
         <td style="width: 100%; height: 45px;"> <!-- change #3 - ensure this is set to a fixed value, as the position: abolute top will be set to this -->
         Hi, I'm cute!
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td> <!-- change #4 - no longer need position: relative here -->
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 45px; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; overflow: hidden;"> <!-- change #5 - top set to the height of the first row -->
               <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;"> <!-- change #6 - this is an entirely new div, this was very helpful -->
                  <canvas id="imageCanvas" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: solid 5px red; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                  Your browser does not support the <code>canvas</code> element.
                  </canvas>
               </div> <!-- change #6 part b - it's closing tag! -->
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

One thing of note, I used to have the body onload method call start, but for IE I had to change it to the javascript img.onload method.  In IE, the canvas would be perfectly aligned the way I wanted, but the canvas was blank.  And if I put an alert of the img.height after the ctx.drawImage, the height (and width) would be 0 - which explains why the canvas would be blank.  I guess the body was loading before the image?  This error only happened in IE11.  Regardless, I changed it and now it works in all browsers that I tested.

Answer (score 1):

Remove absolute positioning and `canvas` will display as expected. Also you can remove redundant wrapper and add `box-sizing: border-box`. Demo:

```css
* {
  /* add this to include borders and padding in width and height */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-UBq5Nb082x0/Tw7KfsY6EWI/AAAAAAAABwE/Joe2aqsoI0k/s1600/maltese_puppy.jpg";

    function start() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
      if (canvas == null) {
        return;
      }
      if (canvas.getContext) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="start();" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; height: 1px;">
        Hi, I'm cute!
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <canvas id="imageCanvas" oncontextmenu="return false;" style="border: solid 5px red; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    Your browser does not support the <code>canvas</code> element.
    </canvas>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Odd.  When I click Run code snippet, no image shows, at all (in IE).

Comment: @JustLooking Yes, but it works when I click "Run code snippet" twice. Very odd:) Can you please test it on your production, maybe it works?

Comment: Yeah, same issue as I mentioned in the other comments.  Once shrunk, it starts chopping the image instead of dock-filling it.  I am on a 2009 laptop, with win7, and can't get tinypic to upload on any of the browsers (firefox, ie11, chrome).  I'm going to have to add it to my original question.

Comment: @JustLooking AFAIK (I could be wrong) canvas is not very good in scaling, are there any reasons you prefer canvas over SVG?

Comment: What's SVG?  But the reason I was using a Canvas was that as I mentioned this will be a wavelength image of a wave file (audio).  And above it in the table, won't be "I'm cute!", but an audio tag.  So as the audio plays, I draw a one pixel line over the image showing where in the audio they are.  So I used canvas so I could draw over the image.  Can SVG get me that? --- just googled, scalable vector graphics. ... Why couldn't IE just work! Hurrumph! lol

Comment: @JustLooking I would recommend you to ask another question because it depends on your requirements. Just drawing a line can be solved using plain HTML/CSS element and moving it can be achieved using primitive JavaScript animation.

Comment: Yes, today was the day to step back, and start over, i guess.  But now you can see how I ended up down this rabbit hole. I got the line drawing code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966912/drawing-over-an-image-in-html5-canvas-while-preserving-the-image and the dock fill code (using absolute) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566323/html-table-with-scrolling-middle-cell

Comment: @JustLooking Just another question: do you actually need a table layout here? You just need 1 element taking height: auto and another taking all remaining screen space, yes?

Comment: yes. thats correct.  though the first row, the "im cute" row, i want two elements side by side.  a drop down taking up 100pixels width, and an audio tag filling the remainder of the width.  thats the top row. the bottom row is the dock filled image.  i would do this any way possible, divs, tables, anything! lol

Comment: I got side-tracked on some production issues today, and finally got to sit down and look at this - and I've got it!  Here's what I've learned, you do have to use position: absolute.  Well, that's what got me there.  And it did require another div tag, as I suggested in my Original Post.  I mean, I agree, if it was just an image, statically it does what I want.  But once you add the "text" (or controls) as the top row, static no longer works.  For example, even in your answer here, it kind of works in IE, but no longer works in FireFox.  I'm about to post an answer with an updated jsfiddle.

Comment: I do love that you took the time to help me.  You've been awesome.  How do I get you reputation points for your time?

Comment: @JustLooking Thank you. Don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas elements display inline, so try displaying it as a block element:

```html
#imageCanvas {
  border: solid 5px red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I dont think that helped me.  Or Im doing something wrong!